# How to avoid duplicate items on PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm designing a GUI based on PyQt4. The GUI is basically a Qtabwidget within a Window. The idea is that every time the window receive a signal, this add a new tab by the method add_tab. when the signal is received for firts time it works perfectly, tab_0 is created, but the next try it's created  the tab_1 twice and the next try it's create  three tabs tab_2  and so on. Does anybody could explain me what's happening and how to fix it? I think it is related with the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StuGF.png)mutable topic but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!!!
this is my code:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    recive=QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        self.resize(695, 577)
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

   @pyqtSlot(str)
   def add_tab(self,numero):
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "tab")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), 
        _translate("Form", "mesa_"+numero, None))
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(int(numero))
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.tabWidget)
        self.tab.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MyWindow()
    window.show()
    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)
    window.recive.emit('0')
    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)
    window.recive.emit('1')

    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)
    window.recive.emit('2')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HXb2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have PyQt5.
Leave one `window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):

    recive = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Form")
        self.resize(695, 577)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 691, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_tab(self, numero):
        self.tab = QWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "tab")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), "mesa_"+numero) 
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(int(numero))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)
    window.recive.emit('0')

#    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)      # <---
    window.recive.emit('1')

#    window.recive.connect(window.add_tab)      # <---
    window.recive.emit('2')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That comes from your way of connecting events:

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.tabWidget)
```

Each time the `add_tab` method is called, a new connection is registered. A quick workaround would be to disconnect the existing signals before.

However, I'm not sure how to do that when the connections were made with `connectSlotsByName`...

> The good practices about connecting and disconnecting signals can be found  [there](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

Comment: Thanks olinox in some way you was right , I was reading about but S.Nick gave me a more specific answer.